# Using a python program that I installed from the command line in Jupyter?

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter

sorry for this really basic question: I installed the [CMSmap](https://github.com/dionach/CMSmap)  program locally and now want to use it in my Jupyter notebook when writing my own code. What is the command to import this program in Jupyter?

I wanted to run the CMSmap tool over a list of URLs. I installed the tool according to the instructions on the website, but I can't run it in Jupyter.

Comment: All the steps you used in python terminal. Open conda prompt and do same steps there. It will word in jupyter.

Comment: Hi there, I am adding this line this in my Jupyter Notebook:
cmsmap https://example.com

But I get an error  
cmsmap https://example.com
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax